# How to Access "Images" in "Resources" via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using google chrome.

[image]

These images are lagging the browser, so I need away to access it and clean it all.

Comment: wasting a lot of bytes ?

Comment: what is exactly you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [asking how to solve the wrong problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).  If your high-frequency ajax calls return images that they don't need, then you are making bad ajax calls.  Deleting the files would be treating a symptom when you should be treating the cause.

Find a way to not download them in the first place.  The result of an ajax call can be scoped, filtered, or even parsed manually.  There's no reason to allow the full result of your ajax call to store these extra resources that you don't want.  If you want to know specifically how to do that filtering, you'll need to post the code that generates your ajax calls.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I'll make a new question of how. I'll take this answer as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

_generated_background_page.html is a file created by an extension installed into Google Chrome.  If you are working on a website (not a Chrome Extension), these files are not delivered by that site and can be safely ignored.

Also... a handful of images won't cause any meaningful lag on a modern browser.

Comment: I'm sending ajax requests per 5 sec and these images keeps loading with it. After a while, it spams 'Images' and lags the browser.

Comment: On a webpage, or are you developing an extension?

Comment: Ah, well you can delete the files by clearing your cache (in the browser's settings).  To figure out why they are downloading I might start by looking at the network tab to see if I can pinpoint what js is triggering it.

Comment: Is there away to access these 'Images' and clean it via javascript?